# CSS File Not Loading in Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

So I've got a webpage which loads fine in Chrome & Firefox.

But in Safari, it only loads 2/3 of the external (linked) CSS files. The file that doesnt get loaded is my own custom CSS file.

Firstly, I've checked the HTTP response headers for that custom CSS file and they look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 08:30:46 GMT
Content-Length: 3387
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Secondly, the header tag has 3 different CSS files in it.

- Bootstrap (from CDN)
- Google Font
- Custom CSS

Here's the header tag:

```
<head>
<link href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Laila:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://104.131.6.40:9001/assets/app.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<..snip..>
</head>
```

The first 2 stylesheets seem to be loading OK (because the page displays like a bootstrap page), but the third one is definitely not loaded.

The URL is:

```
http://104.131.6.40:9001/p/1
```

If you access it in Safari, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What makes you think it's not loading?

Comment: Have you tried hosting the css somewhere else? Just to see if it's Safari not being able to reach the css.

Comment: @Rvervuurt I think its a problem with the webserver, because the images on the page aren't loading either.

Comment: But they are loading when opening the page in Chrome, so it seems to be an access-related thing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

I was using WEBrick (Ruby) server. Apparently there is a bug there that sets an incorrect Content-Length header.

https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/618

Solution is to use thin instead, now it works fine.